# "Openning Mapping Theorem" from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

So need to prove if $f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is linear and onto, then the image of any open set is open. I figured that the first step is probably showing $f$ is continuous, and then do a proof for the Open mapping theorem analogous in Euclidean spaces.  But I'm having trouble on both steps.. It feel that it should be very easy to show that f is continuous but just failed on every attempt..and even if I assume f is continuous, still failed to prove the statement. Please, any input would be appreciated!!

Comment: Show that, up to isomorphism (linear, but then also topological), your mapping is nothing but a projection, in which case this is basic topology.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for the reply, but could you elaborate a bit more? I haven't taken topology, and the isomorphism I know of is a bijection between two linear spaces rather than between two operations.. sorry if this sounds stupid

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint to work with (I think we are working on same problem set... See you in Macro tomorrow).

We know that f is a linear mapping.  Hence $f(x + r) = f(x) + f(r)$ (Think about $f\left(B_{R^n} \left( x, r \right) \right)$).  I think it will be enough to show that a ball around the origin in $R^n$ is mapped to an open ball in $R^m$.

Comment: Nice guess but nope, I don't think you'll find me in Macro, and thanks for the hint though I ended up doing it some other way :)